# How do i turn a comma separated email list into an array with keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say i have a string with comma separated emails like this:

```
$var = 'a@hotmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@yahoo.com';
```

then i explode it by comma like this:

```
$array = explode(',', $var);
```

then i loop through array exploding it again by @ sign like this:

```
$myarray = '';
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $array[$k] = explode('@', $v);
    $name = $array[$k][0];
    $email = $v;

    $myarray .= "'".$email."' => ";
    $myarray .= "'".$name."', ";
}
```

then i remove last comma and echo result:

```
$myarray = rtrim($myarray, ', ');
echo $myarray."<br>";
```

the result will be exactly what i want.

```
'a@hotmail.com' => 'a', 'b@gmail.com' => 'b', 'c@yahoo.com' => 'c'
```

but when i try to use it as an array, it doesn't work. i need to use it as a real array like this (this is the hard-coded way but i need to make it work dynamically):

```
$message_object->myFunction('something', array(
  'a@hotmail.com' => 'a',
  'b@gmail.com' => 'b',
  'c@yahoo.com' => 'c'
));
```

if i try to use $myarray in this way, it fails:

```
$message_object->myFunction('something', array($myarray));
```

so how can i properly turn the comma separated email list into a multi dimensional array (i think it's called)?

Comment: `$myarray[$email] = $name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `$myarray` variable type string to array.

```
$myarray = array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $array[$k] = explode('@', $v);
    $name = $array[$k][0];
    $email = $v;

    $myarray[$email] = $name;
}
print_r($myarray);
```